# Restore MySQL DB to Azure MySQL from a dump file

Tags: mysql, azure, mysql-error-1064

Am restoring MySql Database to Azure MySQL.

```
mysql -h xxx.mysql.database.azure.com -u admin@xxx -p db1 < c:\xxx.dump
```

throw below error:

```
ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. 
Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: ''.
```

When restored to local MySql it works fine.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the advice given in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Azure CLI command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-restore-server-cli) to do that,

```
az mysql server restore --resource-group myresourcegroup --name mydemoserver-restored --restore-point-in-time 2018-03-13T13:59:00Z --source-server mydemoserver
```

Comment: Am trying to restore it to Az from a mysql database dump file supplied by the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command with binary-mode

```
mysql -u admin@xxx -p db1 -h xxx.mysql.database.azure.com -D database --binary-mode -o < c:\xxx.dump
```

Comment: Yes I did tried the way mentioned and got the same issue.